# Get a password from the user in Fabric, not echoing the value

Tags: python, passwords, hide, user-input, fabric

I'm using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org) to automate a deployment. In this process I use the [prompt](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.prompt) function to ask the user some input. In particular I need to ask for a password and I'd like to hide the value the user inputs, like using Python [getpass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html). I'd like to use `prompt` because of the handling of `key` and `validate` args.

Is there a Fabric built-in way to do so, or do have I to change [prompt source](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py#L213) (eventually sending a pull request)?

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to use [`prompt_for_password`](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/network.py#L426) in `fabric.network`

```
def prompt_for_password(prompt=None, no_colon=False, stream=None):
    """
    Prompts for and returns a new password if required; otherwise, returns
    None.

    A trailing colon is appended unless ``no_colon`` is True.

    If the user supplies an empty password, the user will be re-prompted until
    they enter a non-empty password.

    ``prompt_for_password`` autogenerates the user prompt based on the current
    host being connected to. To override this, specify a string value for
    ``prompt``.

    ``stream`` is the stream the prompt will be printed to; if not given,
    defaults to ``sys.stderr``.
    """
    from fabric.state import env
    handle_prompt_abort("a connection or sudo password")
    stream = stream or sys.stderr
    # Construct prompt
    default = "[%s] Login password for '%s'" % (env.host_string, env.user)
    password_prompt = prompt if (prompt is not None) else default
    if not no_colon:
        password_prompt += ": "
    # Get new password value
    new_password = getpass.getpass(password_prompt, stream)
    # Otherwise, loop until user gives us a non-empty password (to prevent
    # returning the empty string, and to avoid unnecessary network overhead.)
    while not new_password:
        print("Sorry, you can't enter an empty password. Please try again.")
        new_password = getpass.getpass(password_prompt, stream)
    return new_password
```

It looks like this is how fabric retrieves password for ssh,  They then set this to `env` using:

```
def set_password(password):
    from fabric.state import env
    env.password = env.passwords[env.host_string] = password
```

Key is easily replaceable by setting `env`, but looks like you might have to validate yourself...